# Comparison with std::nullopt in Catch2 gives unreadable results

Tags: c++, catch2

I have the following check in my cpp test, which is written with Catch2:

```
REQUIRE(foo() == std::nullopt);
```

The test fails with a meaningless message when the function returns `std::optional<int>`:

```
  REQUIRE( foo() == std::nullopt )
with expansion:
  {?} == {?}
```

Is it because Catch2 cannot convert the values to something meaningful, and that's why it shows `{?} == {?}`? What would be the best workaround for it to have a proper error message there?

Comment: in other words, Catch2 does not need to convert `std::nullopt` to evaluate `REQUIRE( foo() == std::nullopt )`. If this fails then because `foo() == std::nullopt` is `false`. Can you include your definition of `foo`?

Comment: It's something like this
`std::optional<int> foo() { if (condition) { return std::nullopt; } return 5; }`

Comment: It works with `return {};`. But I'm not sure I understand what's the issue

Comment: I see it fails when my return value is `int`. How can a make sure that the check works fine both for int and for null?

Comment: That's fine that it fails, the thing is that in the error message it shows `{?} == {?}`, which doesn't give anything to understand what is the issue

Comment: Yes, at first I thought there is an issue with the comparison, but there is not; thank you for helping with that. I rephrased the question – the problem is the output format

Comment: as it turned out that the discussion in comments is not relevant anymore I will delete my comments. Well done to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/tostring.md#top

Given how `std::optional<int>` interferes with `int` I found the `Catch::StringMaker` specialisation to be easier than overloading `operator<<` for `std::ostream` (though you can get both to work).

Try to add this code to your testcases (after the Catch2 header include):

```
namespace Catch
{
    template <>
    struct StringMaker<std::optional<int>>
    {
        static std::string convert(std::optional<int> const &value)
        {
            if (value)
                return std::to_string(*value);
            else
                return std::string("<empty>");
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct StringMaker<std::nullopt_t>
    {
        static std::string convert(std::nullopt_t const &)
        {
            return std::string("<empty>");
        }
    };
}
```

The first part handles `std::optional<int>`, the second handles the cases where you compare to `std::nullopt` (try them one at a time to see the effect).

Comment: I've tried it, but I ended up with the following error message `{?} == <empty>`. 
The second template does affect the message, but the first one doesn't. Am I doing something wrong here?

Just to note, `REQUIRE( std::is_same<decltype(foo()), std::optional<int>>::value );` passes.

Comment: @Nane All I can say is that it works here: https://godbolt.org/z/rcGhbhYqd

Comment: The issue is with my current setup of Catch2, thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I think `has_value` would be a better check:

```
REQUIRE_FALSE(foo().has_value())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with [`CATCH_CONFIG_ENABLE_OPTIONAL_STRINGMAKER`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/configuration.md#enabling-stringification) so that Catch2 provides the correct specializations for `std::optional<T>` and `std::nullopt_t`.

---

`CATCH_CONFIG_CPP17_OPTIONAL` also needs to be defined, but that should be autodetected from combination of C++17 and your stdlib providing `<optional>`.